# "a" or "the" article before a compound noun

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> Avoid including words that are clear from **a/the** file type or otherwise obvious.
>
> ```
> Not recommended:
> presentation_for_google_summer_of_code_2011.ppt
>
> Recommended:
> summer_of_code_2011.ppt
> ```

(The above sentence, as I understand, could be rewritten as *"Avoid including words that are clear from the type of **a/the** file or otherwise obvious."*)

This is an excerpt from my manual about naming files. Which article should I use, **a** or **the**? I know that if I talk about a specific file, I should use **the**, but it doesn't directly answer the question itself.

Comment: (In case speed is of the essence) Both are suitable.  I prefer 'a' slightly, because it covers both well.  'the' sounds a bit more informal.  Also, as a side note, note that "it answers" is the same as "it does answer", and the opposite of "it doesn't answer" :)

Comment: @JustinStafford Yes, I should have written "directly answer" without "s", typo :) Speed is not really the essence, the essence is to understand how these things work, to don't ask something very similar later :) I see that your opinion about a/the here is somewhat different from the JavaLatte's answer...

Comment: Yeah I think he maybe has me convinced; if the question is "What are some good guidelines to naming computer files of different types?" then sometimes I would prefer "a", I think.  Maybe not.  Nah, he's right.

Comment: The manual literally says " a/the"?

Comment: @Acccumulation No, it is an indication of my doubt.

Comment: Then you aren't being clear as to what's a quote and what's not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When talking about a specific thing, we use the definite article **the**. In this sentence,  we are talking about **the** specific type of **the** specific file that we are naming, even if we are explaining a guideline that applies to the naming of any file.

The sentence should therefore be:

> Avoid including words that are clear from **the** file type or otherwise obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know the question is answered, but maybe you could answer whether I should use _"a"_ or _"the"_ in the following sentence: _"The order in which the files are listed in the directory"_. It is a heading of one of the sections of the same document. Is it correct to use _"the"_ in both cases? I ask it here because it was _"The order in which the files are listed in *a* directory"_, but I changed the second article to _"the"_ according to how you described the logic behind of such cases.

Comment: Ask yourself the question "which file type am I talking about?", to which the answer is "the type of the file that I am naming". Now ask yourself the question "which directory am I  talking about?". I think that the answer should be *any directory*, so you use an indefinite article.

Answer (score 2):

There is exactly one property called *type* assigned to each file. This property is unique and unambiguous. When you say **the type** of a/the file, it's perfectly clear what attribute you refer to.

Even if you don't know what file you are talking about (**a** file, **any** file), you still know it's a **file**, and, therefore, it has the **type** property.

Similarly,

> **The format** of a/the file
>
> **The extension** of a/the file
>
> **The size** of a/the file
>
> **The contents** of a/the file

Here are a few examples where the context doesn't define any particular file.

> Windows uses file extensions to determine **the type of a file**.
>
> Some systems keep track of **the type of a file**, while others leave it to the user.
>
> You can determine **the type of a file** using the `file` command.

Answer (score 2):

If you say "words that are clear from a file type", then technically all words that are clear from any file type are included. If you say "words that are clear from the file type", then only words that are clear from the type of the file being discussed are included.